# Problems with nested array after using unset

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, reindex

I have a dynamically built nested array from which i need to drop one or more indexes.

Having scoured the php information pages, i found that using

```
unset($quotes_array[0]['methods'][3]);
```

would remove the last set of data in the array.

But, if i try to use

```
unset($quotes_array[0]['methods'][0]);
```

or any other set apart from the last, it messes up the output that is generated from the array.

For instance, if i had a,b,c,d: I can remove d without issue, but if i try to remove a,
i get a blank radio button followed by b,c, with d missing all together when the array data is processed.

I am assuming i need to reindex the array, but every attempt i've made so far has failed to give the required results, most likely because i'm reindexing $quotes_array, whereas the data i actually need to reindex is that within the 'methods' indices.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unsetting the **`first element`** is easy if you use [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php). array_shift will pop the first element off and reindex your array for you.

```
array_shift($quotes_array[0]['methods']);
```

if you need to unset **`something in the middle`** (such as [ 2 ] out of [ 3 ]) you could use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). First unset the element you want to remove, then reindex them with array_values.

```
unset($quotes_array[0]['methods'][2]);
array_values($quotes_array[0]['methods']);
```

if you wanted to remove the **`last element`** of an array you could use [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php). array_pop will pop the last element off the array. There is no need to reindex in this situation.

```
array_pop($quotes_array[0]['methods']);
```

Comment: Thank you Samuel. Using array_shift for the first element didn't actually work, i ended up with all blank radio buttons, however, unset($quotes_array[0]['methods'][0]);
$quotes_array[0]['methods'] = array_values($quotes_array[0]['methods']); did the trick for me.  If you want to remove 2 and 3, can they be comma separated, or do i use unset twice? Accepting your answer as part of it resolved my issue.

Comment: Hi Samuel. Although it appears to display properly, removing the first element with unset and then reindexing causes an issue whereby the radio buttons then populated from the array data do not pass any info to the next page. Can you see any reason why the array_shift code you suggested doesn't work?

Comment: $quotes_array[0]['methods'] = array_shift($quotes_array[0]['methods']);  does not work. What it does do is assign the "shifted" element to $quotes_array[0]['methods']. To use array_shift it needs to be simply array_shift($quotes_array[0]['methods']); I've tested this and it's now in use.

Answer (score 0):

try

`array_values($quotes_array[0]['methods']);`